# Display calculated length based on column in single query using Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have 2 queries, which shows 2 different data.

for ex: 1 query has `IN` condition which shows `UG_LENGTH` and another query has `NOT IN` condition which shows `AR_LENGTH`. I want that in single query to display both `UG_LENGTH` and `AR_LENGTH` in a single query.

Below is both the query

IN Query

```sql
select RJ_FSA_ID, ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000), 4) AS UG_LENGTH
from NE.MV_SPAN@facid147
where SPAN_REF_NAME IN ('3x40-F-RG-ST-1L','2x40-F-G-ST-1L','1x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x40-F-RG-ST-1L','7x14MM-MICRO','1x14MM-MICRO',
    '3x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x14MM-MICRO','1x40-F-1L-RED','4x40-F-RG-ST-1L') 
and RJ_FSA_ID='MUMB1622'
group by RJ_FSA_ID;
```

NOT IN Query

```sql
select RJ_FSA_ID, ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000), 4) AS AR_LENGTH
from NE.MV_SPAN@facid147
where SPAN_REF_NAME NOT IN ('3x40-F-RG-ST-1L','2x40-F-G-ST-1L','1x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x40-F-RG-ST-1L','7x14MM-MICRO','1x14MM-MICRO',
    '3x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x14MM-MICRO','1x40-F-1L-RED','4x40-F-RG-ST-1L') 
and RJ_FSA_ID='MUMB1622'
group by RJ_FSA_ID;
```

How can I merge both the query?

Comment: You can put a CASE with a condition inside a SUM() and thus having 2 SUM() with each one a CASE with the opposite condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
select RJ_FSA_ID,
       ROUND(
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN SPAN_REF_NAME IN ('3x40-F-RG-ST-1L','2x40-F-G-ST-1L','1x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x40-F-RG-ST-1L','7x14MM-MICRO','1x14MM-MICRO','3x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x14MM-MICRO','1x40-F-1L-RED','4x40-F-RG-ST-1L')
           THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000
           END
         ),
         4
       ) AS UG_LENGTH,
       ROUND(
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN SPAN_REF_NAME NOT IN ('3x40-F-RG-ST-1L','2x40-F-G-ST-1L','1x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x40-F-RG-ST-1L','7x14MM-MICRO','1x14MM-MICRO','3x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x14MM-MICRO','1x40-F-1L-RED','4x40-F-RG-ST-1L')
           THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000
           END
         ),
         4
       ) AS AR_LENGTH
from   NE.MV_SPAN@facid147
where  RJ_FSA_ID='MUMB1622'
group by RJ_FSA_ID;
```

Comment: Also, I want `UG_LENGTH + AR_LENGTH` as 'TOTAL_LENGTH'. for that I am doing like this. `UG_LENGTH + AR_LENGTH` as 'TOTAL_LENGTH' but its not displaying

Comment: @hud Wrap the query above in an outer query and do the calculation in that.

Comment: yes, it's woking now. Also, can we make config table for `'3x40-F-RG-ST-1L','2x40-F-G-ST-1L','1x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x40-F-RG-ST-1L','7x14MM-MICRO','1x14MM-MICRO','3x40-F-G-ST-1L','2x14MM-MICRO','1x40-F-1L-RED','4x40-F-RG-ST-1L'` to fetch values

Comment: @hud Yes, you can do that.